# Printing out 2d list in python 2.7

Tags: python, list, class

I'm sorry for such a stupid question, I'm not used to object-oriented programming (I come from a C background). To put it bluntly, I'm very clueless on classes. First of all, is this how you initialize a list attribute and set each element to None?

```
class World:
    def __init__(self):
        self.arr = [[None for x in range(20)] for y in range(20)]
```

Also, I wanted to check if each value was, in fact, set to none but I don't know how to print it out.

Comment: If you want to index a 2D array consider using a numpy array instead of a list of lists

Comment: Please see my amended answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you accepted the answer I can't delete it, so I will try to amend it.

This is the **wrong** way:

```
mylist = [[None] * 2] * 2    # Definitely not what you want
```

The above is bad because if you do

```
mylist[0].append(1)
```

The output will be

```
[[None, None, 1], [None, None, 1]]
```

The reason is that we didn't create a list of 2 lists, but a list with 2 
references to the **same** list.

The correct way would either be what you already have or:

```
mylist = [[None] * 20 for i in range(20)]
```

I am not sure what you mean by "wanted to check if it was set to None".

Something like this for example?

```
w = World()  # make a world instance
print w.arr  # This should print your 2d list
```

Comment: But be warned that if you were to use, for example, an empty list instead of `None` in this example, each element would be the *same* list. To avoid that, you would use the expression you have in the question.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant. Thank you. I just wanted to make sure it was working properly.

Comment: @WaleedKhan Nice catch! Although it wasn't what the OP asked for, it'd be good to mention it.

Comment: @user2357112 Relax. It was a typo. I fixed it.

Comment: Now you're just showing the OP how to do it wrong after they already had it right.

Comment: @user2357112 What are you talking about?

Comment: The OP was using list comprehensions to avoid exactly the bug you're introducing with `[[None]*20]*20`. Your code creates a list of 20 references to the same list. The OP's code properly creates a list of 20 independent lists.

Comment: Thanks. I inadvertently used the correct way. I appreciate your comments. Python is easy to learn with help like this.